# Proof of an equivalent statement for the convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Can someone provide me a hint to how I should go about proving this statement:

> $2.$  Prove that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ (of real numbers) converges if and only if corresponding to an arbitrary positive number $\epsilon$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n - a_N| < \epsilon$.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get stuck when trying it?

Comment: Hint: Write down first what "$a_n$ converges" means.

Comment: Oh... does this mean that I just need to prove $a_n$ converges to $a_N$?

Comment: No. "$a_n$ converges" means it converges to some real number $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
for one direction, use the inequality:
$$
|a_m-a_n|<|a_m-a|+|a_n-a|
$$

for the other one, one needs the [*completeness* of the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers).

Comment: Thanks! Got it.